# Currency Convert to Word in PHP INR way

Tags: php, ms-word, currency, converters

I am fatriedg an issue while converting the currency in the INR case.
I want to make a function where if the amount does not have 'paisa' then in the last of the word will shows the 'only' word.

```
e.g 1: INR '100.23' will show: One Hundred and Two Three Paisa Only
e.g 2: INR '100' will show: One hundred Only
```

I have tried this code but I don't how I implement this same.

```html
function getIndianCurrency(float $number)
        {
            $decimal = round($number - ($no = floor($number)), 2) * 100;
            $hundred = null;
            $digits_length = strlen($no);
            $i = 0;
            $str = array();
            $words = array(0 => '', 1 => 'one', 2 => 'two',
                3 => 'three', 4 => 'four', 5 => 'five', 6 => 'six',
                7 => 'seven', 8 => 'eight', 9 => 'nine',
                10 => 'ten', 11 => 'eleven', 12 => 'twelve',
                13 => 'thirteen', 14 => 'fourteen', 15 => 'fifteen',
                16 => 'sixteen', 17 => 'seventeen', 18 => 'eighteen',
                19 => 'nineteen', 20 => 'twenty', 30 => 'thirty',
                40 => 'forty', 50 => 'fifty', 60 => 'sixty',
                70 => 'seventy', 80 => 'eighty', 90 => 'ninety');
            $digits = array('', 'hundred','thousand','lakh', 'crore');
        
            while( $i < $digits_length ) {
                $divider = ($i == 2) ? 10 : 100;
                $number = floor($no % $divider);
                $no = floor($no / $divider);
                $i += $divider == 10 ? 1 : 2;
                if ($number) {
                    $plural = (($counter = count($str)) && $number > 9) ? 's' : null;
                    $hundred = ($counter == 1 && $str[0]) ? ' and ' : null;
                    $str [] = ($number < 21) ? $words[$number].' '. $digits[$counter]. $plural.' '.$hundred:$words[floor($number / 10) * 10].' '.$words[$number % 10]. ' '.$digits[$counter].$plural.' '.$hundred;
                } else $str[] = null;
            }
        
            $rupees = implode('', array_reverse($str));
            $paise = '';
        
            if ($decimal) {
                $paise = ' and ';
                $decimal_length = strlen($decimal);
        
                if ($decimal_length == 2) {
                    if ($decimal >= 20) {
                        $dc = $decimal % 10;
                        $td = $decimal - $dc;
                        $ps = ($dc == 0) ? '' : '-' . $words[$dc];
        
                        $paise .= $words[$td] . $ps;
                    } else {
                        $paise .= $words[$decimal];
                    }
                } else {
                    $paise .= $words[$decimal % 10];
                }
        
                $paise .= ' paise only';
            }
        
            return ($rupees ? $rupees . 'rupees' : '-') . $paise ;
        }
```

Comment: The `paise only` is in the wrong place. At the moment it is always added when `$decimal` is true, but not when it's not true. So `if ($decimal){ ... } else{ add paise only }`

Comment: Is it really `Two Three` and not `Twenty Three`?

Answer (score 0):

Here You go.
try this.

```php
<?php
function getIndianCurrency(float $number)
{
    $decimal = round($number - ($no = floor($number)), 2) * 100;
    $hundred = null;
    $digits_length = strlen($no);
    $i = 0;
    $str = array();
    $words = array(0 => '', 1 => 'one', 2 => 'two',
        3 => 'three', 4 => 'four', 5 => 'five', 6 => 'six',
        7 => 'seven', 8 => 'eight', 9 => 'nine',
        10 => 'ten', 11 => 'eleven', 12 => 'twelve',
        13 => 'thirteen', 14 => 'fourteen', 15 => 'fifteen',
        16 => 'sixteen', 17 => 'seventeen', 18 => 'eighteen',
        19 => 'nineteen', 20 => 'twenty', 30 => 'thirty',
        40 => 'forty', 50 => 'fifty', 60 => 'sixty',
        70 => 'seventy', 80 => 'eighty', 90 => 'ninety');
    $digits = array('', 'hundred','thousand','lakh', 'crore');
    while( $i < $digits_length ) {
        $divider = ($i == 2) ? 10 : 100;
        $number = floor($no % $divider);
        $no = floor($no / $divider);
        $i += $divider == 10 ? 1 : 2;
        if ($number) {
            $plural = (($counter = count($str)) && $number > 9) ? 's' : null;
            $hundred = ($counter == 1 && $str[0]) ? ' and ' : null;
            $str [] = ($number < 21) ? $words[$number].' '. $digits[$counter]. $plural.' '.$hundred:$words[floor($number / 10) * 10].' '.$words[$number % 10]. ' '.$digits[$counter].$plural.' '.$hundred;
        } else $str[] = null;
    }
    $Rupees = implode('', array_reverse($str));
    $paise = ($decimal > 0) ? "and " . ($words[$decimal / 10] . " " . $words[$decimal % 10]) . 'Paise' : '';
    return ($Rupees ? $Rupees . '' : '') . $paise . ' Only';
}



echo getIndianCurrency(100.20);
```